# Load NSImage into QPixmap or QImage

Tags: c++, macos, qt, graphics

I have an NSImage pointer from a platform SDK, and I need to load it into Qt's QImage class. To make things easier, I can create a QImage from a CGImageRef by using QPixmap as an intermediate format, like this:

```
CGImageRef myImage = // ... get a CGImageRef somehow.
QImage img = QPixmap::fromMacCGImageRef(myImage).toImage();
```

However, I cannot find a way to convert from an NSImage to a CGImageRef. [Several](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2007/Jul/msg00046.html) [other people](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ConvertNSImageToCGImage) have had the same problem, but I have yet to find a solution.

There is the [`CGImageForProposedRect`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:) method, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm currently trying this (`img` is my NSImage ptr):

```
CGImageRef ir = [img CGImageFirProposedRect:0:0:0];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSImage` is a high level image wrapper that might contain more than one image (thumbnails, different resolutions, vector representations, ...) and does a lot of caching magic. A `CGImage` on the other hand is one plain bitmap image. Since `NSImage` is a so much richer object, there’s no easy way of converting in between the two.

To get a `CGImageRef` from an NSImage you have some options:

1. Manually select an `NSBitmapImageRep` from the `NSImage` (using `[img representations]`) and get the `CGImage` from that.
2. Setup a graphics context (`CGBitmapContextCreate`), draw the image into that, and create a `CGImage` from this context.
3. Use the new Snow Leopard API to create the `CGImage` directly from the `NSImage`: `[img CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:nil hints:nil]`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample to create 16x16 QPixmap with alpha channel using Cocoa

const int width = 16;
const int height = 16;

NSBitmapImageRep * bmp = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
      initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
      pixelsWide:width
      pixelsHigh:height
      bitsPerSample:8
      samplesPerPixel:4
      hasAlpha:YES
      isPlanar:NO
      colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
      bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
      bytesPerRow:0
      bitsPerPixel:0
      ];

  [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

  [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bmp]];

  // assume NSImage nsimage
  [nsimage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,width,height) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction: 1];

  [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

  QPixmap qpixmap = QPixmap::fromMacCGImageRef([bmp CGImage]);

  [bmp release];
```